# Пунктуация в предложении, где присутствует оборот "от и до" с обильным уточнением

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие, дефис

Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно расставить пунктуационные знаки в следующем предложении (в целях анонимности оно сильно изменено):

> Хотелось бы поведать Вам, что мы подвергались постоянным актам
> сознательной и бессознательной агрессии: от президента международной
> компании и бухгалтера местного филиала организации до странного майора
> полиции и его "наипрекраснейшего" доклада.

Также, буду очень благодарен, если объясните принцип постановки пунктуационных знаков в подобных предложениях. Сильно страдаю, когда не понимаю, где, в подобных предложениях, необходимо поставить дефис, а где двоеточие. Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Вот у вас в вопросе — "с обильным уточнением". При уточнении двоеточие не ставится (ставится запятая или тире). Другое дело — перечисление.

Comment: Примечание. Раз вы используете диапазон, то в список должны входить и другие лица (о которых не сообщается) — их должно быть больше. Так принято говорить при однородности: *от уборщика до главы компании; от бедного до богатого; от рядового до генерала*. А в вашем диапазоне однородность не улавливается. Должен быть самый мелкий и самый крупный, которые ограничивают единое целое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь **нет элементов через запятую для перечисления**, поэтому двоеточие плохо подходит. Желательно тире (не дефис, он ставится в середине слова).

Подходит следующее правило Розенталя:
Перед пояснительным членом предложения обычно стоят слова *именно, **а именно**, то есть* (при отсутствии в предложении эти слова могут быть вставлены). При отсутствии пояснительного союза вместо запятой перед пояснительным членом предложения часто ставится тире:
*Эти птицы [стенолазы] добывают свой корм исключительно в воздухе — питаются летающими насекомыми.

Он обладает особой способностью — всё делать вовремя.

Разговор шёл один — о погоде.

Профессия его была самая мирная — учитель.

На выполнение работы потребовалось меньше, чем мы ожидали, — два месяца.*
http://www.old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119

*Хотелось бы поведать Вам, что мы подвергались постоянным актам сознательной и бессознательной агрессии — [**а именно**] от президента международной компании и бухгалтера местного филиала организации до странного майора полиции и его "наипрекраснейшего" доклада.*

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129586/discussion-on-answer-by-oleedd------).

Answer (score 1):

Артём, «дефис» — это  ***короткая*** чёрточка. Через дефис пишутся, например, слова *кто-нибудь, едва-едва* и *по-английски*. А то, что вы имели в виду и что, например, стоит в моём первом предложении, называется **тире**.

Ваше предложение вполне подходит под [правило о знаке после обобщающего слова и перед перечислением](http://www.old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189) (разумеется, в том случае, если в оригинальной фразе перечисляются именно **акты** агрессии, а не их источники, — например, завершение вашей фразы должно бы выглядеть так: *до «наипрекраснейшего» доклада, представленного странным майором полиции*; не пренебрегайте этим, чтобы не страдала логика вашей фразы!). Согласно вышеупомянутому правилу, в этом случае можно ставить как двоеточие, так и тире. Поскольку предложение у вас длинное, тире в данном случае предпочтительнее: разделение с помощью тире более наглядно. Правила постановки двоеточия смотрите [здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150); говоря коротко, двоеточие ставится в тех случаях, когда вторая часть (после двоеточия) разъясняет первую. Пример такого разъяснения из Пушкина: *Дубровский приставил фитиль, выстрел был удачен: одному оторвало голову...* :)

И ещё: союзы как таковые не обособляются запятыми. И если непосредственно после, например, союза *также* не следует обособляемый оборот (а у вас он не следует), запятая после *также* не ставится. Кроме того, обособлять запятыми словосочетание *в подобных предложениях* в данном предложении нет никаких причин.

Comment: Стыдно. Да, придется переделывать предложение. Спасибо Вам!

Answer (score 1):

Фраза стилистически неряшливая, пунктуацией её не спасешь.

> Хотелось бы поведать Вам, что мы подвергались постоянным актам
> сознательной и бессознательной агрессии ***разных лиц***: от
> президента международной компании и бухгалтера местного филиала
> организации до странного майора полиции ***с его*** "наипрекраснейшим"
> докладом.

Это как минимум, в этих случаях двоеточие уместно, так как далее идет список упоминаемых лиц.

А вообще, что это за беллетристика? Кому вы собрались "поведать"? Уж не прокурору ли? Тогда выкиньте все - и напишите содержательную часть в приличествующем ключе.

***Сообщаю (информирую / довожу до Вашего сведения), что имели место факты агрессии со стороны некоторых [должностных] лиц, а именно: ...***

Хотя тут трудно понять, что вы называете агрессией, но это уже на вашей совести.

Comment: Мне очень стыдно) И нет, не прокурору :/

Comment: @АртёмВасилевский А чего стыдиться-то? Ресурс для того и создан, чтобы, помимо прочего, помощь оказывать.   *И нет, не прокурору* - ну в любом случае "поведать" - не для делового стиля.

Comment: Ну, я просто сильно изменил предложение. Но главное, -- перечисление **источников** агрессии, -- оставил. Хм, правильно ли расставлены тире на этот раз? :D

Answer (score 0):

Вы в комментарии писали: «Хотелось перечислить источники этой агрессии», — вот и напишите: *...подвергались агрессии из самых разнообразных источников — от... до...* Или так, как советует behemothus: *агрессии самых разнообразных лиц.* Да, чуть не забыл: *до странного майора полиции **с его «наипрекраснейшим» докладом.*** Чтобы не было «агрессии со стороны доклада».